# SSH - ksh: git: not found

Tags: git, ssh, ksh, bash

I have GIT running on a Solaris server.

From a windows machine I installed cygwin to try to clone a repository hosted on the server.

I do the following:

```
$ git clone username@server:project.git
ksh: git-upload-pack: not found
```

So I try

```
$ ssh username@server echo \$PATH
/usr/bin
```

It seems like git is not in /usr/bin/ but in /usr/local/bin/.
I tried changing the PATH in .bashrc on my home directory on the server to add /usr/local/bin/ ... but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`~/.bashrc` is read by non-login shells, but only by **bash**, and your server uses **ksh**.
`~/.profile` is (I think) universal initialization file, but it is read **only by login shells**.
`~/.kshrc` is typical startup file read by ksh, but only if **ENV** environmental variable is set to it (but see SendEnv in ssh_config manpage).

---

Also you can always pass `--upload-pack=/usr/local/bin/git-upload-pack` option to "git clone" (and then set `remote.origin.uploadpack` configuration variable) if you can't set PATH on remote.  And of course `remote.origin.receivepack` if it can't find git-receive-pack.

Comment: I was not able to set the PATH using .profile, so I tried your method and it worked perfectly. Small modification, had to do: git config remote.origin.receivepack /usr/local/bin/git-receive-pack

Comment: Thx for the help Jakub. Sorry, I accidentally removed my vote and it tells me 'Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited'

Comment: I tried this also on OS X (10.13): `ssh mac 'which git' ` gave `/usr/bin/git`. I changed `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` `PermitUserEnvironment yes`, restarted openssh service, created `~/.ssh/environment` as `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` and tested it with `ssh mac 'env'`. Now `ssh 'which git'` pointed to the correct binary.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like your shell on the Solaris machine is ksh and not bash, which is why your .bashrc isn't being read. Try putting the change in .profile

Answer (score 0):

I had to add /usr/local/bin to my path in .profile for it to be picked up on solaris (and get git upload-pack to work). I always thought it was my boxes that were badly configured, but maybe not so...

Comment: Agreed, just caught that - the .bashrc is most likely not being sourced by the non-interactive git login.