# git set remote path to git executable files over ssh

Tags: linux, git, zsh

I connect over ssh to a distant machine using this in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myserver
    User myusername
    ProxyCommand ssh myserver2 exec nc myserver 22
```

But when I try to pull the remote git repository, I obtain this error:

```
% git pull myserver:~/mygitrepository
zsh:1: command not found: git-upload-pack
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The problem is that my git executable files are not in standard path defined by $PATH. On the remote machine:

```
% which git-upload-pack
/c5/shared/git/1.7.6/bin/git-upload-pack
```

and on the local machine:

```
% ssh myserver "env | grep PATH"
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

ssh doesn't read the remote PATH definition in .zshrc or .bashrc. How can I define the PATH to git executable files over ssh?

Comment: ssh doesn't read any PATH definitions at all because it's just making the connection, it's not your shell. You're actually having a problem where your zsh is to blame (if it doesnt read the .zshrc) or you just have to actually add your PATH additions to your .zshrc :)

Comment: actually ssh doesn't read user configuration file (.zshrc or .bashrc) at all when ssh is launch with a command in argument. The PATH variable is already defined in my .zshrc and git works correctly when I'm connected in an interactive session through ssh.

Comment: then you can simply add the PATH definition to that command, right? (or `source`ing the .zshrc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I've found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603739/ssh-ksh-git-not-found?rq=1). One solution is to set the upload-pack path in the remote using :

```
git pull --upload-pack=/c5/shared/git/1.7.6/bin/git-upload-pack myserver:~/mygitrepository
```

in the client.